# Xpages dojo typeahead drop down list pop up direction

Tags: dojo, xpages, typeahead, xpages-ssjs

I have implemented Xpages dojo typeahead list. In Google Chrome browser, drop down list pops up upwards sometimes and downwards sometimes.

Is it possible to make it pop downwards always?

Comment: If it makes use of `dijit/popup` module you can specify `orient` property. See [docs](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/popup.html#details-of-dijit-popup-open)

Comment: @barbsan: Thanks!